# django_tables2 ManyToMany Columns

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to learn Django and web development aspects and have set myself a challenge of writing some 3rd party tools for the popular action RPG, Path of Exile.

A key feature of any ARPG is collecting loot items, which may have any number of 'stats', these are represented in the model as a ManyToManyField.  I'd like to list a group of items and their stats in table.  I know how to do this with HTML tags in the relevant template.html but would like to use django_tables2 if possible, to reduce repetition etc.

I've played around a bit and read the documentation and the tables.html template but can't see an obvious way of doing this or find any other posts etc, I'd be grateful for any help or a nudge in the right direction.

[Here is a mockup of what I'd like the table to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pClC8.png)  I'm not too bothered about having cell dividers or not but would like to be able to sort the columns of these many to many aspects.

*modely.py*

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(StatNames, models.DO_NOTHING)
    min_value = models.IntegerField()
    max_value = models.IntegerField()

class ItemName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    i_level = models.SmallIntegerField()
    min_dmg = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    max_dmg = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stats = models.ManyToManyField(Stats)
```

*tables.py*

```
class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = poe.models.ItemName
        print("ItemName.type", poe.models.ItemName.type)
        fields = (
                    'name',
                    'i_level',
                    'stat_name',
                    'min_value',
                    'max_value',
                )
```

Here's an example of the html approach I tried out, the variable names are a little different from above but it demonstrates what I had in mind.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Something</th>
            <th>Something Else</th>
            <th colspan='3'>Stats!</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for obj in object_list %}
            {% with obj.stats.count|default:1 as rowspan %}
            <tr>
                <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{obj.name}}</td>
                <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{obj.something}}</td>
                <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{obj.something_else}}</td>
                {% for stat in obj.stats.all %}
                    <td>{{stat.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{stat.min_value}}</td>
                    <td>{{stat.max_value}}</td>
                {% empty %}
                    <td colspan='3'>No stats</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```